# A way for whole Calendar to show after swiping down in Iphone

Tags: iphone, calendar, widgets

I want to see the whole calendar after swiping down. The part where the widgets are. Basically, when you swipe down, you can see the current date but when you try to click it, nothing happens. When you click the weather, the weather shows up so I was wondering if there is a way for the whole calnedar to show in the widgets page are.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any events scheduled for today there's going to be a text in the Notification Center (when you swipe down) right under the current date saying "Your first meeting today...". Tap that and it'll bring up the Calendar.

If you don't have anything scheduled for today, you can scroll to the bottom of the Today view and tap the [Tomorrow section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmBWk.jpg) instead.

Comment: Consider adding some additional details and/or screen caps to illustrate what you are answering here.  We are looking for more than a single line answer.